# I can not check true or false on window.onload in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am have 3 li blocks:

HTML:

```
<li class="contact">
    <p class="circle-name"></p><p class="person">Brad Morison</p>
    <section class="sub-drop">
        <span class="number">
            <a href="tel:+123-45-67">+123-45-67</a>
        </span>

        <span class="time-work">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Time work guides">
        </span>
    </section>  
</li>
```

and plus yet 2 some blocks with another name in `class="person"`.
If i am click on name (`class="person"`), that class get new `class` and new styles. If i am again click, then remove class(i use `classList.toggle`).

When i am click on any name in `class="person"`, that name write in localStorage (example: if i click `<p class="person">Brad Picture</p>`, then in localStoge write key 'Brad Picture' with value `true`). Value in localStorage = `true or false`. True if new class was add, false if again click(delete new `class`).

My problem:

If `key` in `localStorage` = `true`

`window.onload` i am try check:

```
if(name in localStorage == true){ //and === true
  //Add class
}
```

or

```
if((localStorage.getItem(name)) == true){ //and === true
  //Add class
}
```

that no work

full JS code:

if on load page `name` = `true` add new `class`

```
guide = document.querySelectorAll('.person');

index = 0;

        [].slice.call(guide).forEach(names);

            function names(n,i){
                let name = n.innerHTML;
                    n.addEventListener('click', function(){
                        index = i;
                        check = n.classList.toggle('day-off');
                        localStorage.setItem(name, check);
                    });

                    if(localStorage.getItem(name) === true){
                        n.classList.add('day-off');
                    }

                };
```

What's my wrong. What should I do?

Comment: `localStorage` stores data always in string data type, so if you stored a boolean, it will be stored as the string equivalent. To check, do `if(localStorage.getItem(name) === "true")`

Comment: @trincot thanks you, i am try it and no work code(

Comment: @trincot that work only for last block. another ignored value

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for my english. good luck